# Java QueryDSL 3.6.0 Projection.bean(Person.class, person.firstName, person.count())

Tags: java, spring-boot, orm, jpql, querydsl

I am using QueryDSL in my project to return a list of Person groupBy LastName and no of persons with that lastName. Below is the Person.java

```
@Entity
class Person {
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private boolean isCitizen;
     private int age;
     private int groupByCount; //Property to return groupByCount - could use Group tuple for this, but doing a research trying to set it as an object field.

     //Constructors to support n! ways of object creation - where n is no of fields in the object
     public Person(String lastName, int groupByCount){
       this.lastName = lastName;
       this.groupByCount = groupByCount;
     }

     public Person(int age, int groupByCount){
       this.age = age;
       this.groupByCount = groupByCount;
     }

     public Person(boolean isCitizen, int groupByCount){
       this.isCitizen = isCitizen;
       this.groupByCount = groupByCount;
     }

     // keeps going to cover all possible constructors - i want to avoid this for maintainability reasons - want to be able to build objects dynamically with different parameters

     //Below is code for Getter and setters for above fields
}
```

The QueryDSL query which uses these Constructors are below.

```
personRepo.getQueryDSL().createQuery(person).groupBy(person.lastName)
.list(Projections.constructor(Alarm.class, person.lastName, person.count());

personRepo.getQueryDSL().createQuery(person).groupBy(person.age)
.list(Projections.constructor(Alarm.class, person.age, person.count());

personRepo.getQueryDSL().createQuery(person).groupBy(person.isCitizen)
.list(Projections.constructor(Alarm.class, person.isCitizen, person.count());
```

How to avoid writing those n! constructors for a class with n fields using QueryDSL ?? I tried Projections.bean like below, after removing the constructors in the Person class

```
personRepo.getQueryDSL().createQuery(person).groupBy(person.isCitizen)
.list(Projections.bean(Alarm.class, person.isCitizen, person.count());
```

It complains .count() is not a valid expression. It is notable to assign the value of count to groupByCount field in person object. How to set groupByCount of the person object with person.count() value using Projections.bean method ??

Thanks in Advance. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chained .as method on top of .count to groupByCount attribute as shown below. This way I was able to avoid writing n! constructors.

```
personRepo.getQueryDSL().createQuery(person).groupBy(person.isCitizen)
.list(Projections.bean(Alarm.class, person.isCitizen,
person.count().as(person.groupByCount));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [`Projections.fields`](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/Projections.html#fields-java.lang.Class-com.querydsl.core.types.Expression...-) is what you're looking for. Have the setter names in the POJO mirror the column names in the query - it looks like you already have this in place.